# Bootstrap 3 menu - two collapse buttons - only one open at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a menu in bootstrap 3. When it gets down to mobile size, I have two collapse nav-toggle buttons. As default, when one is open, it just gets stacked on top of each other. What I would like is one drop down open at a time.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-search">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <div id="test2" class="nav-search collapse">
            <div class="search_box">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div><!-- end search_box -->
      </div><!--/.nav-search -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I searched and found this, **but that is for bootstrap 2**:
[Bootstrap Menu - Two Collapse buttons which toggle each other? Meaning, only 1 open at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570062/bootstrap-menu-two-collapse-buttons-which-toggle-each-other-meaning-only-1-o)

I feel like I am missing something easy. Below is a jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bootstrap714/RfsS9/4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have got the name of the event wrong. You need to call it on `on('show.bs.collapse'...` instead of just on `on('show'...`.

[Here is a fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfsS9/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed something so easy.

Comment: No worries, it is an easy mistake to make - The event name was `'show'` in bootstrap v2, they changed it for v3.

Answer (score 0):

Found a kind of "hackish" solution

if, the sibilings button, doesn't have a collapsed class, click on it.

```
$('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function () {
    if(!$(this).siblings('.navbar-toggle').hasClass('collapsed')) {
       $(this).siblings('.navbar-toggle').click();
       }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t96Ry/