# cannot read shorthand javascript/query

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, syntax, shorthand

i've spent ages trying to understand bootstrap's navigation bar, mainly by spending 4-5 days reading stackoverflow posts

& finally i think i've found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338409/bootstrap-3-menu-two-collapse-buttons-only-one-open-at-a-time) that helps!!!

trouble is, i can't understand the accompanying javascript/jquery code.  i'm guessing its a shorthand version of js or something but just what it means i cannot decipher

basically, its the javascript code that appears on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Bootstrap714/RfsS9/4/) jsfiddle page

```
$('.navbar').on('show', function () {
  var actives = $(this).find('.collapse.in'),
    hasData;

  if (actives && actives.length) {
      hasData = actives.data('collapse')
      if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return
      actives.collapse('hide')
      hasData || actives.data('collapse', null)
  }
});
```

so, if anyone can explain to me what the code is doing on a line by line basis it'd be really cool

the first line i understand. its the weird-ass syntax in the next 6 lines that have me mystified

Comment: do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation ?  `if ( a && b )` == `if a AND b are both true`.  `a || b()` === `if a is NOT true, then execute b`.   Is this what you do not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var actives = $(this).find('.collapse.in'),
    hasData;
```

This creates two variables. One with elements picked from current scope that match the selector `.collapse.in`, and one empty variable.

```
if (actives && actives.length)
```

If actives exists and contains more than zero elements, do the following...

```
hasData = actives.data('collapse')
```

Retrieve arbitrary data stored under the key `collapse`. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/ for more info.

```
if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return
```

If `hasData` exists and `hasData.transitioning` is truthy, stop function execution.

```
actives.collapse('hide')
```

Call the `collapse` function on `actives`. This is not a native jQuery function, so you'll have to look up whatever plugin it comes from to make sense of the argument being passed in.

```
hasData || actives.data('collapse', null)
```

If `hasData` is truthy, skip this line. Otherwise, set the arbitrary data in `actives` variable to null.

Comment: cheers dude, u're a prince.   

first line syntax i have seen before but didn't remember (feel a bit of a dumbass about that).  last line i've never seen.  as for the collapse function on actives, that's part of the Bootstrap collapse.js plugin.

cheers again